# javascript bug with canvas putImageData function inside for-loop

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, canvas, putimagedata

I was playing around with pixel-level manipulations on an HTML canvas and ran into a bug with the `putImageData()` function. Here's my code:

```
var can = document.getElementById("canvasID");  
var ctx = can.getContext("2d");  
var picToAlter = document.getElementById("image");   
var pix = ctx.createImageData(1, 1);  
var colData = pix.data;  
colData[someNumber] = someValue;   
ctx.drawImage("image", 0, 0);  
for(let i=0;i<=can.width; i+10){  
  ctx.putImageData(pix, i, 0);  
}
```

When I try to run this code in my browser (Firefox) the page simply fails to load no matter how long I wait, and, eventually, asks me if I want to stop the loading process. The problem seems to lie with my for-loop, because if I run a single instance of the code, it works. The moment I put it in a loop, though, it goes back to not loading. This is true even if I use a while-loop instead. I know that `putImageData` can be slow, but I feel like I'm missing something obvious that makes the loop infinite, but I just can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to grab image data immediately (without preloading), you probably see a blank canvas. You should only run your code after preloading the image.

```
picToAlter.addEventListener('load', yourDrawingMethod)
```

Also, your for-loop is probably not behaving how you would expect. You don't want to hit `can.width` because it would actually be out of bounds because it's starting at zero. Also, your iteration statement isn't actually iterating. You need to use an assignment operator like `i = i+10` or `i+=10`. Taking those issues into consideration, you would end up with something like this...

```
for(let i = 0; i < can.width; i+=10){
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Yup, the iterator was the problem. Changed it and it worked immediately. Thanks!